# "few if any" vs "few, if any"

Tags: non-restrictive

Below are two sentences for the discussion:

1. *There may be few if any other plumbers working in Moore's town.* (Source: from an LSAT)
2. *There may be few, if any, other plumbers working in Moore's town.* (This is my own adaptation by adding commas)

If I understood correctly, few means a very small amount of number. Also, [By MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/few%20if%20any), "few if any" means not very many or none at all.

So is it correct to say: 1. expresses two possible scenarios: 1-2 other plumbers and none; whereas, 2. only mention the scenario of 1-2 other plumbers?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It looks like to me that the first sentence has just been carelessly punctuated.

Comment: It would be hard for me to realize that an LSAT probably contains an ungrammatical sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase 'if any' is *parenthetical*, no matter what is meant.

A parenthetical phrase (**which can be a single word or a quite long clause**) adds meaning to the sentence in which it appears but is not a fundamental part of the sentence.

Parenthetical phrases should always be surrounded with punctuation either *parenthetical commas*, brackets or, **in some cases**, dashes.

This means, **as Mozibur Ullah says in a comment above**, that the first sentence is incorrectly punctuated. Changing the punctuation does not change the meaning.

In the above paragraphs the *parenthetical phrases* are written in **bold type**

Answer (score 0):

Both meanings match the Mirriam-Webster definition. You may also see it written as *"... few (if any) ..."*